# PHP/MySQli problems returning mysqli_fetch_array

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, fetch

so I know I can connect to the db fine, I've created a couple tables in the db successfully. But when it comes to selecting the data in a table and putting it into a table the Column names show, but the table is empty. No data was returned in the fetch array while loop. I've searched for awhile and can't seem to see anything wrong with my code. Indentation came out kind of wacky on here.. Thanks

```
require_once('mysqli_connect.php');
$query = "SELECT * FROM sample";
$response = @mysqli_query($conn,$query);

if ($response) {
  echo '<table border="1" align="left" cellspacing="5" 
cellpadding="8">
  <tr>
  <td align="left"><b>empID</b></td>
  <td align="left"><b>first_name</b></td>
  <td align="left"><b>last_name</b></td>
  <td align="left"><b>gender</b></td>
  <td align="left"><b>state</b></td>
  <td align="left"><b>city</b></td>
  <td align="left"><b>zip</b></td>
  <td align="left"><b>latitude</b></td>
  <td align="left"><b>longitude</b></td>
  <td align="left"><b>company</b></td>
  <td align="left"><b>dept</b></td>
  <td align="left"><b>phone</b></td>
  <td align="left"><b>email</b></td>
  <td align="left"><b>ip_address</b></td>
  <td align="left"><b>MAC</b></td>
  <td align="left"><b>credit card</b></td>
  </tr>';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)) {
echo '<tr>'; 
echo '<td align="left">'. $row['empID'] . '</td>';
echo '<td align="left">'. $row['first_name'] . '</td>';
echo '<td align="left">'. $row['last_name'] . '</td>';
echo '<td align="left">'. $row['gender'] . '</td>';
echo '<td align="left">'. $row['state'] . '</td>';
echo '<td align="left">'. $row['city'] . '</td>';
echo '<td align="left">'. $row['zip'] . '</td>';
echo '<td align="left">'. $row['latitude'] . '</td>';
echo '<td align="left">'. $row['longitude'] . '</td>';
echo '<td align="left">'. $row['company'] . '</td>';
echo '<td align="left">'. $row['dept'] . '</td>';
echo '<td align="left">'. $row['phone'] . '</td>';
echo '<td align="left">'. $row['email'] . '</td>';
echo '<td align="left">'. $row['ip_address'] . '</td>';
echo '<td align="left">'. $row['MAC'] . '</td>';
echo '<td align="left">'. $row['credit card'] . '</td>';
echo '</tr>';  
}
echo '</table>';
} else {
 echo "Error showing table: " . $conn->error;
}
$response->free();
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: You're not checking for errors, so have a gander at your error logs to see if there is a problem.

Comment: Please, never use `@` on functions unless you really have a seriously good reason. It hinders finding out problems like this.

Comment: @JayBlanchard He's checking for errors with `if($response)`. He prints the error message in the `else` block. But since he's seeing the column heading, there's no error.

Comment: The only explanation I can see for this is that the table is empty.